# Duvida com slide em html

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiR8d.jpg) I have a slide in the home of the site I'm developing, there are several banners, are shown 2 at a time on the screen, but I need the slide to work as follows, passing the images one at a time from right to left.

Example:

| Fig.1 and Fig.2 | after | Fig.2 and Fig.3 | after | Fig.3 and Fig.4 | after | Fig.4 and Fig.1 | after | Fig.1 and Fig.2 | ...

But for now they are moving two by two like a normal slide.

I think it's right and use carousel, can someone give me a light please?

Comment: Hello! Stack Overflow is an English forum, you might be looking for [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Try this one: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ it allows you to set the number of slides to show as well as the number of slides to scroll